# Convert a List<T> to csv file using FileHelpers

Tags: c#, .net, filehelpers

I have a class like so

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location {get; set; }
}
```

This is then converted to a list of the type above with data. I want to use filehelpers to convert my list object to a csv string.

Currently I am doing this

```
    List<MyObject> objList = new List<MyObject>();

    //populate objList here
    //..
    //..

    var feng = new FileHelperEngine<List<MyObject>>();
    string str1 = feng.WriteString(new MyObject[]  { objList });
```

This is giving me an error

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MyObject[]' to
 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.List<MyObject>'
```

The other error is :

```
Cannot implicitly convert type
'System.Collections.Generic.List<MyObject>'
to 'MyObject'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You are trying to populate a `MyObject[]` with a `List<MyObject>`. See the problem? A `MyObject[]` needs to be populated with `MyObject`. You could just try the [ToArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819(v=vs.110).aspx) method on `List<T>`. Something like `feng.WriteString(objList.ToArray())`

Comment: ... and you probably want to change the type parameter of the `FileHelperEngine` to just `<MyObject>` without the List too.

Comment: Did both of the above and its still the same error

Comment: And looking at the docs, it looks like `WriteString` takes a `IEnumerable` anyway, so you shouldn't need to covert to an array at all. Just pass it your list.

Comment: So you should have something like `var feng = new FileHelperEngine<MyObject>();` and then `string str1 = feng.WriteString(objList);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
var feng = new FileHelperEngine<List<MyObject>>();
string str1 = feng.WriteString(new MyObject[]  { objList });
```

You want this:

```
var feng = new FileHelperEngine<MyObject>();
string str1 = feng.WriteString(objList);
```

Answer (score 3):

If the type is known and very simple, you can do it without any external Libraries:

```
File.WriteAllLines("output.csv",list.Select(
    obj => String.Join(", ", new Object[] {obj.Name, obj.Location, ...})
));
```

Comment: can this be done without using a file? I want to just output to a string.

Comment: Yes. Just replace `File.WriteAllLines("filename", ...` with `string result = String.Join(Envionment.NewLine, ...` and you're done. Or use foreach and a StringBuilder

Comment: Thanks Zotta. While you did give an interesting alternative which I am tempted to use, I will award the correct answer to Cory below as his answer uses FileHelper engine as asked in the question above. Upvoted both your replies.

Answer (score 0):

The compile errors are with this syntax:

```
new MyObject[]  { objList };
```

The curly braces are what's known as a [collection initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx), which expect **individual elements** of the collection.  Since you're making an array of `MyObject`, the initializer is expecting single object, but you're passing a *collection* of those instead.  If in the future you really need to have an array (instead of any other `IEnumerable` types), just call LINQ's [`.ToArray()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb298736(v=vs.100).aspx)

As others have pointed out, the [`.WriteString`](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/FileHelpers.FileHelperEngine.WriteString_overload_2.html) is looking for any `IEnumerable` anyway, so just passing your existing `List<MyObject>` is fine.  Also, the generic type of the `FileHelperEngine<T>` is expecting the type you want to write out, which is just `MyObject` and not the collection.

```
var feng = new FileHelperEngine<MyObject>();
string str1 = feng.WriteString(objList);
```